# How to make sure that same thread will invoke a com+ component in server machine

Tags: c#, .net, com, remoting, com+

I have a COM dll exposed inside a COM+ application in a remote machine.

There are 2 functionalities exposed by this component,

1. Initialise
2. ProcessCommand.

This COM component has a rule that a request for ProcessCommand should always gets invoked from same thread which called Initialise method (this actually initialses several internal components). So in remoting perpective how can I make sure that same thread will be used to call both methods in server when invoked from client machine. Any configurations in server component help me in achieve this?

Comment: Just make this component apartment threaded no?

Comment: Some additional info, if it helps someone someway,the component was making use of thread local storage

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is by using the same client "instance" to the COM+ component. In other words, don't *instantiate, call Initialize, discard*, and then *re-instatiate, call ProcessCommand, discard*. Each client-side "instance" corresponds to a server-side thread.